# Ответ сервера JSON

Tags: json, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, хочу попробовать чтобы сервер отдавал только JSON, а на стороне клиента был JS который бы обрабатывал данные сервера и решал что с этими данными делать (на сервере PHP)

Comment: А я хочу попробовать ананасы в шоколаде. Только о своих желаниях я пишу в блоге или Твиттере, а здесь задаю конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Так попробуйте, что вам мешает-то?

Answer (score 5):

Сервер:

```
echo json_encode("This string will encode to JSON format");
```

Клиент:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", url: "mysyte.com",  
    data: "somting data", dataType:"json",  
    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data); // здесь прийдут данные в ЖСОН  
    }
});
```

Comment: Или сокращенный вариант:

    $.getJSON('mysite.com', {data: somedata}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

Answer (score 0):

Я для этих целей использую `jQuery Templates`. Данные собираются в структуры и в таком виде подсовываются `jsrender`.
Пример можно посмотреть [X13.Host](https://github.com/X13home/X13.Host/tree/Development/htdocs).

Answer (score -1):

Данные в формате json есть смысл передавать в таком виде:  
сервер:

```
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'ok'));
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
  'url':'site.ru',
  'type':'post',
   success:function(e){
     var resp = $.parseJSON(e);

     alert(resp.response);

   }
})
```

Comment: А теперь найдите 10 отличий между вашим ответомм и ответом @deivan, опубликованном пять часов назад. Один из основных принципов программирования гласит: Don't Repeat Yourself (не повторяйся). Если вы хотели дополнить ответ, следовало оставить под ним комментарий, а не писать идентичный пост.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что через json имеет смысл передавать объект. нет смысла передавать строки.

Comment: dataType:"json" лучше делать, на всякий случай.