# Можно ли с помощью AJAX выбрать условие в PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function (data) {
    $("#form").html(data);
});
```

Обработчик:

```
if (1) {
    echo "1";
} elseif (2) {
    echo "2";
} elseif (3) {
    echo "3";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Можно ли например, если выполняется 1 условие тогда `AJAX` выводит как прописано `$("#form").html(data);`, если 2-е условие, тогда вот так `$("#err").html(data);` и т.д. Реально ли такое осуществить AJAX-ом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ответ сервера JSON](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244377/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-json)

Comment: конечно. вы можете выводить что угодно, и это будет в data в обработчике done.

Comment: @Darth, можно подробнее? Или вы имеете в виду то что Visman?

Comment: @Visman, если это вы отредактировали вопрос, я еще не знаю решило ли это мою проблему, никогда не работал с json.

Comment: @emtecif, я ни чего не редактировал.

Comment: сейчас напишу подробный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую такой подход

на сервере создаёте массив, который заполняется в зависимости от результата ваших проверок, например так:

```
$result = ['result' => true, 'data' => 'some data'];
echo json_encode($result);
die(); //В некоторых фреймворках предусмотрена функция вроде ->sendJson($result);
```

на клиенте в обработчике `done` в вашей переменной `data` будет содержаться json пришедший с сервера, который вам и предстоит обработать:

```
var data = $.parseJson($data);
if(data.result) {
  //какие то действия, например $(body).html(data.data);
} else {
  //какие то действия
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вольны php выводить что угодно, необязательно использовать json или что-то еще. Когда мне нужно выполнить одну операцию, лично я делаю так -

PHP (вообще я на node.js пишу, но принцип тот же):

```
//выполняется какие-то действия..
if(error)echo error;
//еще действия, все ошибки выводятся..
//Всё сделано
echo "ok";
```

JS:

```
$.ajax( ... ).done(function(data){
   if(data=='ok'){
       //Всё хорошо
   }else{
       console.error(data)
   }
});
```

Вы можете расширить эту схему, например в вашем случае вы выводите цифры, тогда можете сделать так:

```
$.ajax( ... ).done(function(data){
   switch(data){
       case "1":
           $("#form").html(data);
       break;
       case "2":
           $("#err").html(data);
       break;
       case "3":
           //...
       break;
       default:
           console.error(data) 
   }
});
```

JSON - это просто лучший (на мой взгляд) способ передавать структурированную информацию для подобных ajax-запросов. Вы можете использовать XML, csv или любой другой формат.

Comment: А если я вывожу не цифры?

Answer (score 1):

Если прямо в лоб на ваш вопрос, то вот код.
JS

```
 $.ajax({
     url: this.action,
     type: this.method,
     data: $(this).serialize()
 }).done(function (response) {
     // добавить проверку данных – response может быть не объектом и тогда будут ошибки при обращении к свойствам
     $("#" + response.selector).html(response.data);
 });
```

PHP

```
// данные по умочанию
$result = array('selector' => 'html', 'data' => 'success');
if (1){
    ...
}
elseif (2){
    ...
}
elseif (3){
    ...
}
else{
    $result = array('selector' => 'err', 'data' => 'error');
}
echo json_encode($result);
die(); // завершение скрипта, на всякий случай
```

Дальше все зависит от вашей архитектуры приложения